# Continuing iMacros Script After Prompt For User Input

Tags: prompt, imacros, pause

iMacros 10.0.2.1450 (Free for Firefox)

Firefox 65.0.2

Windows 7 Pro (Version 6.1 Build 7601; SP1)

I'm trying to run a script and the two variables I need to input are the customer's name and the customer's phone number. I made the discovery that the script will just keep on running in the background while the prompts are awaiting input, and by the time you get the data entered, it's way past that page, and the result shows as "Undefined" in the final product. This is what I have:

```
PROMPT "Enter Customer Name:" !VAR2
PROMPT "Enter Customer Phone Number:" !VAR3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:editPage ATTR=NAME:00N60000001yXQW CONTENT={{!VAR3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=NAME:editPage ATTR=NAME:cas15 CONTENT=Customer<SP>Name:<SP>{{!VAR2}}
```

I thought I'd try PAUSE, but found I need to manually resume once I'm ready. WAIT is also an option, but I don't really like that one either. Not sure if there is another option, but does anyone know if it's possible to get the script to continue only after the values are entered into the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I needed to move the variable prompts to be the very first step in the script.